# Choosing a Database for querying on different combination of fields

Tags: database, performance, indexing

**I am looking for the most suitable DB to use for the following requirements:**
1) 1 table with ~ 50 million records, ~ 15 columns/fields (strings), no joins are required
2) query by each combination of the columns is efficient (if required, by creating indexes ahead, but then if reduces update performance and increase size of DB)
3) after adding a new record, we might also update some fields there later on (efficiency for the update is less important)
**Usages:**
return top X (sorted by some fields) for satisfying a query

Comment: What are the performance requirements? Query response time 99% and TPS for update, insert, select?

Comment: Select will be used in the crucial path, so I am mostly trying to limit the time it takes to get records by some fields. Inserts are running "offline" so some slowness is acceptable for having quick response for select

Comment: That's not really a requirement, it's too broad. You need to know how quick you need it. To make select for top X quick you would need to create indexes for each (or most critical) column combination if you would need to query those ~50M each time. What would be the size of a subset you need to query in common case?